# VS Code JSX errors despite (I believe) correct React syntax

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

[image]

VS Code keeps reporting this as a Problem... I don't see anything wrong, what am I missing?

Things I have tried:

- Adjusting the language type in the lower right (set here to "JavaScript JSX")
- Attempted to load this file with all extensions disabled and I see the same thing
- Re-installed VS Code
- Restart computer
- Crying

The file opens just fine in a browser and renders my content.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      const app = document.getElementById('app');

      function Header() {
        return (<h1>Why error?!?</h1>);
      }

      function HomePage() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Header />
          </div>;
        )
      }

      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(app);
      root.render(<Header />);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code will complain because you have the file association set to JSX when this file is technically an HTML file. The outer tags are invalid in the context of a JSX file unless they're being returned by some function.

If you remove all the HTML tags between L1-7 and L24-26, the VSC errors will go away but your file will no longer render.

If you set your file association to HTML, the errors will go and the file will continue to be rendered as expected. However, you will lose any JSX-related linting until you break this out into its own script file that is then added to your `index.html`.